# Deleter does not delete the property in python

Tags: python, properties

I have the following code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.__password = ""

    @property
    def password(self):
        if len(self.__password) == 0:
            return ""
        secret = self.__password[0]
        for i in range(len(self.__password) - 2):
            secret += "*"
        secret += self.__password[-1]
        return secret


    @password.setter
    def password(self, new_pass):
        if len(new_pass) < 6:
            for i in range(6 - len(new_pass)):
                new_pass += "#"
        self.__password = new_pass



    @password.deleter
    def password(self):
        if len(self.__password) > 10000:
            del self.__password


u = User("John")
u.password = "s"
print(u.password)
u.password = "L0nger passwords ArE M0r3 Secure 0r s0 th3y s@y!"
print(u.password)
del(u.password)
print(u.password)
```

The issue is that the deleter does not delete the password property and I can still print it after  I call the deleter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think `len(self.__password) > 10000` would be true? When I `print(len(self.__password))` it shows `48`, which means `del` is never executed.

Comment: You are right. I did that "if" just to test something and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are only deleting the property when the length is >10000. The following code produces the outcome you seek:

```
    class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.__password = ""

    @property
    def password(self):
        if len(self.__password) == 0:
            return ""
        secret = self.__password[0]
        for i in range(len(self.__password) - 2):
            secret += "*"
        secret += self.__password[-1]
        return secret


    @password.setter
    def password(self, new_pass):
        if len(new_pass) < 6:
            for i in range(6 - len(new_pass)):
                new_pass += "#"
        self.__password = new_pass



    @password.deleter
    def password(self):
        if len(self.__password) > 10:
            del self.__password


u = User("John")
u.password = "s"
print(u.password)
u.password = "L0nger passwords ArE M0r3 Secure 0r s0 th3y s@y!"
print(u.password)
del(u.password)
try:
    print(u.password)
except:
    print("failed!")
```

The outcome:

```
s****#
L**********************************************!
failed!
```

Comment: Yes! I noticed that I forgot to remove the 'if'. I used it just to test something and forgot about it. Thank you!